# Is the Count of a not null List object always greater than 0?

Tags: c#, .net, list

In C#, if a `List()` object is not null, does that also mean that the `Count` will always be greater than 0?

For example, if you have an object `intList` of type `List<int>`, is the following code redundant?

```
if (intList != null && intList.Count > 0) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: `new List<int>().Count` // => 0

Comment: no, it could be not null and  empty

Comment: What sort of person downvotes useful questions? Why bother?

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 what on Earth makes this a useful question? Downvoting useless questions is half of how we prevent them from competing with good questions.

Comment: Gosh I don't know. Oh no I do ... it's the fact that null != a count of 0, but to someone who's new they might seem like the same thing. You must have been at the 681 reputation point in the past. Maybe you've forgotten what newbie questions look like.

Comment: Let's rewrite that question: _"Does having a bag **also** mean that it has items in it?"_ It's nonsense.

Comment: Sorry to have asked such a stupid question. It was just something I always wondered. The bag explanation makes sense. I just didn't think of it like that.

Comment: It's not a stupid question, and indeed canon's sarcasm has actually produced a rather appropriate analogy. What are the chances?! ;0)

Comment: canon - good analogy, bad sarcasm. Not everyone visiting this site is a professional programmer; presumably you would prefer to vet credentials prior to being allowed to post?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is perfectly valid to have an empty list:

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
bool isEmpty = intList.Count == 0; // true
```

If you want to know if a list is not null and contains at least one  item you could also use the new C#6 [null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

```
List<int> intList = null;
bool isNotEmpty = intList?.Count > 0; // no exception, false
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! That answers it perfectly. And thank you for the tip about the null condition operator.

Answer (score 1):

No, that code is not redundant.  `intList` can be null or `intList.Count == 0`.  Here are some cases:

```
List<int> intList = null;

Console.WriteLine(intList);  // it will print 'null'

intList = new List<int>();

Console.WriteLine(intList.Count); // it will print '0'
```

In modern C# you can use the [Null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) to simplify the check though.  This syntax is equivalent in performance to testing for `null`, it's just a syntax sugar to simplify this common check.

```
if (intList?.Count > 0) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers are self explained.
Just try to add a bit more

if (intList != null && intList.Count > 0) 
Here the count is checked to make sure the intList has at least one item in it before performing any operation on the list.
The most common use case we check for count in addition for null check is when we want to iterate thru the items of the list.

```
if (intList != null && intList.Count > 0) 
{
    foreach(var item in intList)
    {
        //Do something with item.
    }
}
```

If list is empty then there is no point trying iterating thru it.

But if intList is NOT null that does NOT mean that it has count > 0. Items need to be added in to the list if count has to be greater than zero.